# После загрузки на хостинг перестали работать некоторые элементы

Tags: laravel, vue.js

В основном весь вопрос в названии. На локальном хостинге все работало нормально, но после загрузки фрагменты html, например, switcher или checkbox, компонентов Vue перестали отображаться. Я искал весь день для информации, я ничего не могу найти, кто сталкивался прошу помощи

Comment: что за фрагменты html

Comment: написал же checkbox, к примеру отсутсвует. 
<input type="checkbox" /> - его нет даже если через inspect смотреть

Comment: наверное скрипты не подключились, как выглядит страница, что выдает в консоли?

Comment: Компонент работает полностью, но без некоторых фрагментов. В консоли все гут